# Caveats of printing unicode characters in Python

Tags: python, unicode

The following code:

```py
print('\N{WAVING BLACK FLAG}')
```

is as simple as it can be. Yet on some machines it prints the character as expected, on other it raises a `UnicodeEncodeError` with a message `'ascii' codec can't encode character '\U0001f3f4' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`.

**Why printing a character can *sometimes* lead to `UnicodeEncodeError`?** There is no mention about any encoding in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print). And is there any way how to make sure the string will be printed without raising any exceptions?

---

I managed to isolate a reproducible example:

```py
import subprocess
import sys
subprocess.run([sys.executable, 'test.py'], env=dict())
```

The `test.py` contains just the single print statement mentioned above. This example raises a `UnicodeEncodeError` on all tested machines... but only when tested with Python `3.6`. When tested with Python `3.7` it prints the character as expected.

Comment: Python itself can't really control this; if you run it in a place where it is forced one way or another to use ASCII for printing things, you can't print non-ASCII. My hunch is that you are on Windows but there are probably ways to force the environment to only support ASCII e.g. inside some IDEs.

Comment: It's not in the docs of `print`, but the one for [`sys.stdin/out/err`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If otherwise your locale settings are the same for the tests on both 3.6 and 3.7, this may be due to [PEP538](https://peps.python.org/pep-0538/) coming into effect since python 3.7

PEP538 coerces the C locale to UTF-8.